# Is $F_xF_{zy}=F_yF_{zx} $ true for any $C^{\infty}$ function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Is $F_xF_{zy}=F_yF_{zx} $ true for any $C^{\infty}$ function $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$? What if we add the assumption $F_z\ne 0$?

---

Motivation:

If $F:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^\infty$, and at $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, $F_z\ne 0$, then in a neighbourhood of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, $F(x,y,z)=F(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ gives a function $z=z(x,y)$ s.t. $F(x,y,z(x,y))=F(x_0,y_0,z_0)$.

We have
$$z_{yx}=(z_x)_y\ \  \underbrace{=}_{?}\ \  \left(-\frac{F_x}{F_z}\right)_y=-\frac{F_{yx}F_z-F_xF_{yz}}{F_z^2}$$

(**Edit**: The underbraced equality is incorrect, since $z_y=-\frac{F_y}{F_z}$ is not true for all $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}$.)

Symmetrically we have $$z_{xy}=-\frac{F_{xy}F_z-F_yF_{xz}}{F_z^2} $$

Since $F_{xy}=F_{yx}$ and $z_{yx}=z_{xy}$ we yield $$F_xF_{zy}=F_yF_{zx}. $$

However, the above argument assumes $F'z\ne 0$, and it is very indirect. Is $F_xF_{zy}=F_yF_{zx} $ true for any $C^{\infty}$ function? Do we have a direct proof?

Comment: consider $F=xz+y$

Comment: it is not true even if we add $F_z\neq 0$Consider $F(x,y,z)=x^2+(y^2+1)z$, then $F_xF_{yz}=4xy, F_{y}F_{zx}=0$. But I don't find mistakes in your proof

Comment: well, i know where you are wrong. $z_{yx}= \mathrm{what you write}$ is only true for $(x,y,z)$ such that $F(x,y,z)=F(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, but $z$ does not need to have relation with $x,y$

Comment: @Koobe  Thank you for your indeed helpful comment. I have used your example to step into my argument. In this example, on the surface $F(x,y,z)=0$ (which contains points $p$ s.t. $F_z(p)\ne 0$ like $(1,1,-\frac{1}{2})$ ), $z_y=(-\frac{x^2}{y^2+1})_y=\frac{2x^2y}{(y^2+1)^2}$, while $-\frac{F_y}{F_z}=-\frac{2yz}{y^2+1}$. $z_y=-\frac{F_y}{F_z}$ only holds for those $(x,y,z)$ with $F(x,y,z)=0$, not for every $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, i.e. $z_y=-\frac{F_y}{F_z}$ is not an equality as two functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$, so we can not infer they have the same partial derivative wrt $y$.

Comment: @Asigan Yes, that is what i was thinking